# Exporting complete projects to be imported in a new installation

Tags: object, export, project, jbpm

I need to export a complete project (with all its objects) from a jBPM environment (local installation) to be imported in a new jBPM environment (in a server installation).

I'm using the jBPM Server distribution, exactly the jBPM 7.74.1.Final server (single zip) distribution and I have install it in my local machine. I haven't using Git or similar.

I want to export an specific project from MySpace, with all its contained objects (diagrams, data objects, work definitions, forms, ).
I can import a project from in MySpace, but its not possible (or I don't be able to see how) to export a complete project directly to be imported in a different jBPM installation (in example, I make the project in my local installation and when its working fine I want to export and then import in the server installation (production environment).

I'm working in two differents environments.

The first one (a local installation in my labtop) its where I make and test the first project version until I get the correct one that makes that all I need.

This its a screenshoot of the project properties that I have to copy to paste in the import project screen in the second environment:
[Project settings: url in local installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn9tr.png)

Take a look the url (marked in blue) of the local environment installation.

The second environment its the installation in a server where we deploy tested project and use to create instances and so on. When I try to import the project from the pasted project url of the first environment (local machine) I have this error and not be able to import:
[Import project option: server installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm1wZ.png)

Take a look the url (marked in blue) of the server installation. Its different to the first one (local).

I have seen other option to Download a project:
[Download project option, that export a zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4JPW.png)

This option download the project  as a 'zip' file, but I don't find a option to import this type files as a project. The import project option only allows to include the url field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone your project using the Business Central URL provided in the project properties.

Comment: Dear Richard, thanks for your comments.
I probe this option previosly, but this one only works when I'am working over the same jBPM installation. If I do that you say me, I can duplicate the project.
But, in my case, I'm working in two differents installations.
I have modify and add information in my question with two screenshoots to a better explication and understood.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).